# Is there a settable parameter controlling max HTTP post size / length in IIS 7, IIS7.5+?

Tags: http, iis, post, asp-classic, size

I have a client with staging and production systems with identical app code in both. The code is classic ASP but I do not see this as part of the issue. A specific page of the web app includes a form in which an HTML string is being edited in a textarea. This code has worked for years without issue and operates for other clients without a problem. With a specific HTML template, on staging there is no issue when they post to the server, but on production the receive a 'HTTP/1.0 400 Bad request' response.

Wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes lists lists HTTP 400 as 'The request cannot be fulfilled due to bad syntax'. However other HTML strings can be edited and posted without issue on production from which I deduce that this is unlikely to be the real issue.

I know that IIS has been improved over the years with various defences and limits to deny buffer overflow exploits etc. I wonder if there is a byte length restriction on post size.  Searching the web brings up many similar questions about PHP, Apache, etc, but nothing obvious re IIS, and the similar questions in stackoverflow are close but not so close as to provide an answer.

Whilst I have genuine and current issue with this, this post is also partly to make a beacon for others with the same issue.

Comment: More info: I've now found out that production is HTTPS whilst staging is HTTP, and by experiment we think the 400 error happens when the posted data exceeds 128 characters.

Answer (score 2):

sure is the default is 4096KB ie 4MB, look at maxRequestLength in the web.config

http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;295626

Comment: Thanks @Luke. Would that be the IIS web.config? Only this is classic ASP and not dot net. Also, reading the linked post, it covers large file uploads rather than post data. Also, we have found by trial and error that the 400 error happens when the posted data exceeds 128 characters.

Comment: Sorry i didnt catch the classic ASP bit, from what ive read there is a limit to the size of the url supported, the recommendation is that when posting via the URL dont exceed 255bytes, however the actual limit seems more like around 2KB. It may also be that the posted data you are sending is not safe to be putting in the URL